# Java- Operators order

Tags: java, operators

Why `a=b+++c` is parsed as `a=b++,+,c`? 
It can be as a= b,+,++c? Is there any order or rule followed by lex tool?

```
 int a = 20, b = 10, c = 0;

         // a=b+++c is compiled as
         // b++ +c
         // a=b+c then b=b+1
         a = b+++c;
         System.out.println("Value of a(b+c),b(b+1),c = " + a + "," + b + "," + c);
```

output :

```
Value of a(b+c),b(b+1),c = 10,11,0
```

Comment: Yes, there [is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Java code is tokenized, it will take the longest possible Token as mandated in the [Java Language Specification Section 3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> ### 3.2. Lexical Translations
>
> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn:
>
> 1. A translation of Unicode escapes ([§3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)) in the raw stream of Unicode characters to the corresponding Unicode character. A Unicode escape of the form `\uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is `xxxx`. This translation step allows any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.
> 2. A translation of the Unicode stream resulting from step 1 into a stream of input characters and line terminators ([§3.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.4)).
> 3. A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a sequence of input elements ([§3.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5)) which, after white space ([§3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.6)) and comments ([§3.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7)) are discarded, comprise the tokens ([§3.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5)) that are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar ([§2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.3)).
>
> **The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.**
>
> > Thus, the input characters a--b are tokenized (§3.5) as `a`, `--`, `b`, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization `a`, `-`, `-`, `b` could be part of a grammatically correct program.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the lexer is just greedy. When it finds a new + its first order of business is to check whether it can be completed with a character that forms a multi-chars operator, such as ++ or +=

You can see it with the differences between a++1 and a + + 1. One is invalid and the other, though idiotic, is valid.